# Javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to insert this JavaScript code (that is borrowed from someone else with credit given appropriately) into an HTML page. I understand how to use the simple `document.write()` to display text with JavaScript and am also pretty fluent in Java but am having a hard time trying to get these functions to work properly. For lack of a better word or words I am trying to get some animation to happen using JavaScript. I found various tutorials that show some JavaScript logic and print to the screen but none of them use animation and if they do show some animation they do not show how to include it into HTML. I want to display the animation properly within the HTML page. I have been reading through the w3 schools tutorials on JavaScript and most of them either return something or use the document.write to pull information from a form or a browser. I believe this might have something to do with creating an object to use for displaying the movement in the algorithm or with the DOM for JavaScript.

The idea behind my JavaScript is, I would like to simulate a working example of the bresenham line algorithm. There is an example of this here: [Bresenham line algorithm](http://scriptnode.com/article/bresenhams-line-algorithm-in-javascript/)

I also saw plenty of tutorials for including the JavaScript in a secondary file and referencing the JavaScript using the src tag but I would like to keep the JavaScript at the end of the html page please.

I am also using Dreamweaver for the development of the HTML & JavaScript page.

The code is listed below. Also please feel free to list a website or tutorial I can reference to view more information on this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Bresenham's Line Algorithm</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

/**
* Bresenham's line algorithm function
* by Matt Hackett [scriptnode.com]
* @param {Object} el The element to target (accepts both strings for id's and element                 *objects themselves)
* @param {Number} x1 The starting X coordinate
* @param {Number} y1 The starting Y coordinate
* @param {Number} x2 The finishing X coordinate
* @param {Number} y2 The finishing Y coordinate
* @param {Object} params Additional parameters [delay, onComplete, speed]
*/
var bresenham = function(el, x1, y1, x2, y2, params) {

var
    interval,
    b,
    m,
    sx,
    y;

var init = function() {

    var dx, dy, sy;

    // Default parameters
    params = params || {};
    params.delay = params.delay || 10;
    params.onComplete = params.onComplete || function(){};
    params.speed = params.speed || 5;

    // No point in doing anything if we're not actually moving
    if ((x1 == x2) && (y1 == y2)) {
        plot(x1, y);
        params.onComplete();
        return;
    }

    el = ((typeof el === 'string') ? document.getElementById(el) : el);

    // Initalize the math
    dx = x2 - x1;
    sx = (dx < 0) ? -1 : 1;
    dy = y2 - y1;
    sy = (dy < 0) ? -1 : 1;
    m = dy / dx;
    b = y1 - (m * x1);

    interval = setInterval(next, params.delay);

};

/**
 * Execute the algorithm and move the element
*/
var next = function() {

    y = Math.round((m * x1) + b);
    plot(x1, y);
    x1 += (sx * params.speed);

    if (x1 >= x2) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        params.onComplete();
    }

};

/**
 * Move the target element to the given coordinates
 * @param float x The horizontal coordinate
 * @param float y The vertical coordinate
*/
var plot = function(x, y) {
    el.style.left = x + 'px';
    el.style.top = y + 'px';
};

 init();
 };


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is I have copied the code from Matt's bresenham example from the link above and pasted it into an HTMl document but when you run it in a browser nothing is displayed? Any idea?

Comment: The bresenham() function is expecting a number of parameters (el, x1, y1, x2, y2, params), where el is meant to be a reference to an element on the page (or, optionally, a string). But your page doesn't have any elements on it, and you don't seem to call the bresnehan() function at all. View the source for the page you reference and search for the code that starts with YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady( - note that this makes use of a Yahoo script library that is beyond the scope of this question to explain. It also uses `el = document.createElement('div')` to create the red box that is animated.

Answer (score 2):

For me the code is fine. Maybe you just need elements to move in your page. According to the documentation of the function you need to specify the id of an element present in your page.

If you intend to run it at the startup of your page you will need to wait that the DOM of your page is constructed before doing any operation on the DOM. Else your function might try to access elements that are not yet constructed.

(There are several javascript frameworks that allows it cross browser)

Declare in the body the elements you want to be affected by your algorithm.

```
<div id="elt1" style="position:absolute; top : 200px; left : 200px">element1</div>
```

Then in chrome using the console I typed this and I got the animation working. I guess you shall declare the style of your element `position:absolute` because your algorithm uses `top` and `left` CSS properties that work with absolute positioned elements.

```
bresenham("elt1",100,100,300,300,null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've asked a very open question, so I'm at a loss how to answer it. I assume your page had some HTML on it that you've cut out to save space, but I think we probably need to see it (or at least some of it).

In general I can suggest that you avoid the w3 school website like the plague. Go here: http://w3fools.com for an explanation of why, and then scroll down to their What Can Be Done section for some good alternative references for JavaScript, HTML and CSS.

Avoid document.write() - especially don't try to use it to update your page after it has loaded, something I assume you'll need to do a lot if you're coding an animation, but in general you won't need document.write() at all. Google yourself a tutorial on `document.getElementById()` - a function that returns a reference to an HTML element on your page; you can use the returned reference to change that element's text, styles (and hence location), etc.

Don't worry about including the JavaScript in a separate file at this stage. There are good reasons for doing so in a real-world website, but if you are just experimenting and learning it's probably easier to keep everything in one page.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://htmldog.com/ and http://www.w3schools.com/ for basic introductions of how html, css and javascript interact.  Also check out [www.getfirebug.com](http://getfirebug.com/) for an intro to debugging JavaScript.  Once you have this base understanding it becomes a lot easier to debug your programs and search for answers to questions you have.

A brief scan of the code shows that you are calling to an HTML element `el` via `getElementById('el');` Unless you are writing the output directly to the document as you suggested using `document.write()` or `alert()` you have to have html to display the output of your code.

From a broader view what you want is first an understanding of how javascript and html interact, then you can start googling for tutorials to complete specific elements of whatever you are trying to build ie "how to display output using innerHTML()"...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that although you loaded in the **utilities** to do something, you don't have any code that utilizes it.

For example:

```
function hello() {
    alert('Hi!');
}
```

The code above should tell the user "hi", right?

Wrong.

The code to tell the user "hi" is there, but I never told it to, so it wouldn't.

Your page isn't doing anything because you need to give it instructions.

From looking through the code on that page, and the source for the animator, I can tell you this:

You need to add a call to `brensenham` and you need to give it details of what to do.

The details it needs are:

- The element to animate
- The beginning position
- The finishing position

So what you need to add to the end of that script tag is:

```
// We need to make sure the elements are ready.
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // Get the element and set up some details.
    var element = document.getElementById('whatever-its-id-is'),
        beginningX = 0,
        beginningY = 0,
        endX = 100,
        endY = 100;

    // Move the element.
    brensenham(element, beginningX, beginningY, endX, endY);
});
```

Then change beginningX, beginningY, endX, and endY to whatever you actually want them to be.

I can tell that you're brand new to this whole thing, so I hope that was simple enough.

Comment: Sorry not sure what happen to my body tag. I re added it. The question is I have copied the code from Matt's bresenham example the link above and pasted it into an HTMl document but when you run it nothing is displayed? Any idea?